# Checking for duplicate records in a table using javascript with an extra check based on one of the checkbox's value?

Tags: javascript

Below is the table generated from an asp.net gridview control,

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="gridHeader">
             <th scope="col">th1</th>
             <th scope="col">th2</th>
             <th scope="col">th3</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <input type="textbox">Name1</input>
                 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">Married</input>
                 <input></input>
             </td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <input type="textbox">Name2</input>
                 <input type="checkbox">Married</input>
                 <input></input>
             </td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td>
                 <input type="textbox">Name3</input>
                 <input type="checkbox">Married</input>
                 <input></input>
             </td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

In the table above if i try to enter a name that already exists in the name column a  validation message "duplicate entry" appears as per my js function. Now, I want to modify this method so as to prevent this error message from appearing in the case of a duplicate entry of name provided the value of Married checkbox of the two records is different. For e.g if one is married and the another is not and vice-versa then the validation message shouldn't appear.
I can check the duplicate entry of name using

```
function detectDuplicateEntries() {
        var names = "";
        var count = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < pagesize; i++) {
            ControlSerial = i + 2;
            var name = getElementById(prefix + "gvwUserNames_ctl" + ((ControlSerial < 10) ? "0" : "") + ControlSerial.toString() + "_userName").value;
            if (name.length > 0) {
                count++;
                if (names.indexOf(name) > -1) {
                    showValidationError();
                    return;
                } else {
                    HideDuplicationError();
                    names += name + "|";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I am unable to add a proper condition in the above method to check for the "Married" checkbox so as to simultaneously check it along with the names list.

Comment: Do you know how to get the info of the checkbox into a variable? Another way to put it: `var married = getElementById( <do you know what goes here?> ).value;`

Comment: A couple of things: first I would clean up your html a little bit, I think those empty cells should actually include the Married checkbox and the following blank input. Second, the correct syntax to write an input element is <input type='textbox' value='Name3'/> or <label> <input type='textbox'/> Name3 </label>. I'm not sure what "pagesize" is nor how the variable "name" is getting populated as I do not se any elements that have an id attribute.

Comment: It will take some time, but I really recommend looking into how to query the DOM (jQuery is a good library to do this). The best solution here might be to loop through the rows of the table and then determine if the name is correct based on the checkbox "checked" property.